# TensorFlow2 / Keras: input_shape seems to not have an effect when subclassing keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When accessing the output of an intermediate layer I always received the error message: `AttributeError: Layer l has no inbound nodes.` I read that one has to determine the `input_shape` in the entry layer to overcome this problem:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='classifier')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.flatten(inputs)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return self.classifier(x)
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

After this failed attempt, I tried to reconstruct my model using `tf.keras.Sequential` and again specified the `input_shape` for the first layer:

```py
tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='classifier')
])
```

This, on the other hand worked!

So I asked myself why the first approach didn't work. To test this I specified arbitrary/wrong `input_shapes` for the subclassed model like this:

```py
class WrongInputShapeModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WrongInputShapeModel, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(42, 42, 42))
        # ...
```

I noticed that this model still functioned with MNIST (which has 28x28 images). That let me to believe that the keyword `input_shape` has no effect when defining a model subclassing `tf.keras.Model`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From your model subclassing code, it looks like you are not returning the model's forward-pass output. Maybe that's the reason it didn't work.

This should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='classifier', activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.flatten(inputs)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return self.classifier(x)
```

And then, just as an example:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = MyModel()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3), loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
             metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Now, `Flatten` input shape is actually defined by the shape of the layer's input tensor, so it does not require an `input_shape` argument. `input_shape` is an attribute of `Layer`, so you can pass it, but the layer's forward-pass doesn't use it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the return statement in this post. Actually that was not the problem. And I must specify the input_shape so that I don't receive the error saying that the model does not have inbound_nodes